# How would I generate list of dates and git commits?

Tags: github, terminal

I wrote some code that generates a github contributions-style heatmap in the terminal given a csv file that contains timestamps and some unsigned value.

I'd like to generate a csv that contains dates and the number of github contributions I made on that date.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` for this job. Also, flags like `i`, `A` and `color` will help you cleaning things up a bit. Also, output the result in a .csv file using `>`
use `man grep` to know a more about its flags.

Try using:

```
git log | grep -E -A 2 --color "commit|Date" > output.csv
```

You could also add --summary flag to log.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `git log` and a custom format:

```
git log --date=short --format="%an %ad [%h] %s" | cut -d ' ' -f1 -f2 -f3 -f4- | sed -E 's/ /,/' | sed -E 's/ /,/' | sed -E 's/ /,/'
```

I get:

```
Lachlan,Miller,2019-03-25,[e20b847] Rename method
Lachlan,Miller,2019-03-25,[6c47dbf] Add a POC using JS
lmiller1990,2018-04-12,[c295307],Add song class
lmiller1990,2018-04-12,[876cbe2],Add timer
```